# C#, Условия заполнения матриц

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]Есть 14 вариантов матрицы, для каждого варианта нужно придумать условия по которому матрица будет заполняться, смог первые 2 сделать, дальше никак не могу. Синюю область нужно заполнить, белая пустая.
Условия для первых 2 :
1 : i>=j;
2 : i<=j;
Код :

```
 class Program
            {
                public delegate bool MatrixType(int i, int j);
                static int Len;
                Program()
                {
                    Console.Write("Length : ");
                    Len = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());// Creating a Length of all Arrays and Matrixes
                }    
    //Base Matrix
            static object[,] CreateMatrix()
            {
                object[,] arr = new object[Len, Len];
                return arr;
            } 
static object[,] FillMatrix(object[,] Matrix)
        {   
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < Len; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Len; j++)
                {
                    if (j > -i + Len)
                    {
                        Matrix[i, j] = (int)random.Next(1, 20);
                    }
                }

            }
            return Matrix;
        }
 static void PrintMatrixArray(object[,] arr)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < Len-1; i++ )
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < Len-1; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0,4}", arr[i, j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program pro = new Program();
            Console.WriteLine();
            // PrintArrays();
            PrintMatrixArray(FillMatrix(CreateMatrix()));
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так это математика,  а не программирование) постройте просто графики для каждой, точнее плоскости, определяемые неравенствами и получите ответ. Тут не придумывать надо)

Comment: Простите, не могли бы вы привести пример одной такой плоскости

Comment: Например, прямая в 3/4 будет описываться как `-x + len`. Судя из вводных, матрица квадратная

Comment: А как тогда заполнить область под/над ней?

Comment: И х это i или j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы посмотрите внимательно на рисунки, то увидите, что вся синяя зона всегда (за исключением 1 - 4 случаев) формируются пересечением двух прямых (диагоналей матрицы)  и условием больше/меньше относительно прямой:

1. `y = x`
2. `y = -x + len`

`x` - `i`

`y` - `j`

Все что вам нужно, нарисовать эти две прямые на листочке и посмотреть при каких условиях больше/меньше области будут пересекаться

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зеленая линия - график `j = i`

Красная линия - график `j = -i + len`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Серая зона - `j > i`

Коричневая - `j < i`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Желтая - `j < -i + len`

Фиолетовая - `j > -i + len`

Тем самым вы получите 4 зоны, комбинируя которые вы сможете получить любую фигуру из вашего задания

Comment: В этом и состоял вопрос, при каких условиях они формируются

Comment: Я понимаю что есть две диагонали, но мне сложно понять как заполнить области сверху или снизу диагоналей

Comment: Ну так порисуйте на листочке) Вы ж просто хотите получить готовое решение, не показав ваш собственный ход мысли) Подскажу вам с 10ой фигурой. Верхний треугольник формируется, когда j > i и j < -i + len

Comment: А нижний формируется при i > j и j < i = j ?

Comment: Нет, нижний (9 фигура) формируется при i > j и j > -i + len

Comment: Не выводит нижний треугольник, и верхний с ошибкой при len = 6

Comment: @MaksLavriv дополнил ответ для вас

Comment: Спасибо, последний вопрос, я уже понял как сделать, другие, области, но вопрос только к фиолетовой, я подставляю условие, но оно выводит только 3 нижних числа фиолетовой области

Comment: @MaksLavriv 3 нижних это какие?

Comment: Добавил фото в описания вопроса

Comment: Проверьте работу с len. Не забывайте,  что у вас  граничные элементы идут не с координатами (0; 6), а (0;5)

Comment: Я по этому и 6 пишу, с Len все хорошо, ну с другим условием работает

Comment: Приложите текущий код

Comment: Прикрепил в вопросе

Comment: @MaksLavriv Не `+ len`, а `+ len - 1`. У вас же диагональ идет от `[5, 0]` до `[0, 5]`